# How to make background-color in the sidebars be as long as the textarea? (simple grid made by myself)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I'm making a simple website, with simple javascript code, that is based on the assumption, that when the user click the button, some lines are added. Everything works perfectly, beside the part with backgrund color of sidebards. When I add another line to the site, col-1 background is not working, I can only see white place (I've made simple grid by myself). More: there is no color at all, all the time. Maybe someone here knows how to fixed it?

```
<section class="grid-container section1">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="talking-div">
        <ul class="talk">
          <li class="animate-talk">text!</li><br>
          <li>text.</li><br>
          <li>text.</li><br>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="talking-button">
        <div class="books answer">text.</div>
        <div class="celestia answer">text.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-1">
    </div>

    </div>
    </section>
```

CSS styling:

```
  .grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .row&:after, .row&:before {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .col-1 {
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      background-color: #87cefa;
    }

    .col-10 {
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      background-color: #E1FEFA;
    }

      li {
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 1.45em;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: 0 0 1.5em 2em;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      background: #eb4492;
      font-size: 19px;
      max-width: 90%;
      min-width: 44px;
      min-height: 12px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .talking-button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2%;
}

.answer {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #1b3669;
  margin: 12px 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.45em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #CCE6FF;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-size: 19px;
  border: none;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-width: 44px;
  min-height: 12px;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kkuvqxc/

Comment: What are sidebars in your code? It is very hard to follow your question

Comment: I don't see a `textarea` or sidebars in the code you provided.

Comment: the side-bars, - maybe it's the nodes where the `class="col-1"` attr is?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. By filling the col-1s, I can see the background: https://jsfiddle.net/2kkuvqxc/1/
For the background to be as long as the textarea(the tallest block of all) you need something like this: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 0):

propably you need add the class

> .talk{   background-color: //color that you need; }

because the talk class is affecting the ul